# How can I be sure that a certain laptop (Lenovo Y500) supports two external screens?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I would like to buy a Lenovo Y500 laptop, which has an nVidia GeForce GT 650M SLI video card and Intel® HM76 chipset. The laptop has two video outputs, one HDMI and one VGA.

I would like to use it with two Dell U2412M screens (1920x1200), one with a HDMI-DVI cable and the other with a VGA-VGA cabel. Is this supposed to work?
(I don't expect the two external screens AND the laptop screen to work together, I would like to close the lid of the laptop and work with the two external screens only.)

Comment: I've gone through the manual and their website; that was a waste of time wasn't it! :)  If it were me, I'd ask Lenovo direct. Or, depending on whom you're buying it from, ask them if they'll offer money back if it doesn't support it! +1 for good clear question

Comment: Thanks for your time :). I have asked on the official Lenovo forum already, haven't got any reply yet.

Comment: I don't think this question is too localized. The question is stated that way in order to get an answer not just about that specific laptop model, but to get some guidelines about how to find out the same thing about any other laptop model, so people with other kinds of laptops can benefit from the answer as well.

Comment: I've got an official response, it should work: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Y500-with-two-external-screens/td-p/1143245